# Call a function by XML

Tags: magento, module

I am developing a Ecommerce website by using version Magento 1.6.

I need to call a function through XML to send a mail(to admin) after an order was placed.

I plan to develop a new module to manage these type of work.

Let me know, how to call the function through XML or any other way to build the module?

Comment: This is unclear. What's the XML for? You should create an Observer that observes Order creation and emails the admin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, We are unable to call any functions through XML.

I wrongly expose my need, My need is how to call magento events through XML.

I found the solution and get done the work.